# Explanation for logical operators example in Eloquent JS

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

I have problems understanding following example from Eloquent JS book :

```js
console.log(
  1 + 1 == 2 && 10 * 10 > 50 // true
);
```

Can someone explain it to me, step by step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)
:

- `+` has precedence of 13
- `==` has precedence of 10
- `*` has precedence of 14
- `>` has precedence of 11
- `&&` has precedence of 6

So, the code is equivalent to:

```
1 + 1 == 2 && (10 * 10) > 50 // group * (precedence 14)
(1 + 1) == 2 && (10 * 10) > 50 // group + (precedence 13)
(1 + 1) == 2 && ((10 * 10) > 50) // group > (precedence 11)
((1 + 1) == 2) && ((10 * 10) > 50) // group == (precedence 10)
```

Then simplify:

```
((1 + 1) == 2) && ((10 * 10) > 50)
((2) == 2) && ((10 * 10) > 50)
(true) && ((10 * 10) > 50)
(true) && ((100) > 50)
(true) && (true)
true
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, we have one plus one, and we're checking if that's equal to two (it is).

```
1 + 1 == 2
```

Then we have a logical AND operator (`&&`) which checks if the statements on both sides of it are true. So far, the above is true, so processing continues.

Finally we are multiplying ten and ten (100) and checking if it's greater than 50 (it is).

```
10 * 10 > 50
```

And finally the AND operator sees that both arguments are true, and gives our result:

```js
 

console.log(1 + 1 == 2 && 10 * 10 > 50);
```